# Laravel make array of another array objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have general data array and I need to get array of specific data inside this general array so I can match it against my database.

## Code

```
$nums = [];
foreach($request->phones as $phone) {
    foreach($phone['_objectInstance']['phoneNumbers'] as $number) {
        $nums = $number['value'];
    }
}

$contacts = User::whereIn('phone', $nums)->get();
```

> PS: `$number['value']` is the data that I want to make array of it.

## Sample data that I receive in backend

[image: aravel]

## current error

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/....../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 918

exception: "TypeError"
```

## Question

How can I make array of my numbers?

> Ps: please if you know cleaner way to write this code, than my code above don't hesitate to share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `$nums` to be a new string on every iteration of the loop, rather than appending it to the array.

Just switch this line out:

`$nums = $number['value'];`

For

`$nums[] = $number['value'];`

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) are the docs for `array_push()`, which is the long way of writing the second line.

Comment: that fixed the error thanks but why i cant get array of my users list? `$contacts` I mean i should get 2 result i just get 1

Comment: You can stick a `->toArray()` after your `->get()` to convert it to an array. If it's only including one contact, you should check that `$nums` is correct, and that it correctly matches your contacts.

Comment: no have any rest, simply make array of numbers and find users who has any of those numbers

Comment: But `$contacts` isn't being returned or sent to the browser, so how are you looking at it in the inspector?

Comment: data of contacts i'm getting in my app (debug mode) so that screenshot i sent was result of `$contacts`

Comment: `$contacts` should right now return users of id `2 and 4` but it only returns user id 2.

Comment: How is `$contacts` being returned from your PHP? It looks like it is returning an array, but the numbers you're supplying only match one of your contacts.

Comment: ok sorry for that i found the issue, value in my database had a 0 less. my apologize

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `$nums` array, but inside the loop, you re-declaring it by a string again. 
Fix the array assignments like that.

```
$nums[] = $number['value'];
```